# Relationship between Fourier coefficients of $f\left(x\right)$ and $f^{-1}\left(x\right)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Say I have a function $f\left(x\right)$, which can be expressed as a Fourier Series:

$$f\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k e^{ikx}$$

Define the inverse of $f\left(x\right)$ as, $f^{-1}\left(x\right)=1/f\left(x\right)$, with its Fourier Series:

$$f^{-1}\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} {c'}_k e^{ikx}$$

Is there a known relationship between ${c'}_k$ and $c_k$? I.e. if I know $c_k$, can I get ${c'}_k$ directly?

For my specific case I am interested in functions for which the following are true:

1. $x\in\left[0,2\pi\right]$
2. $0 \lt f\left(x\right)$
3. $f\left(x\right)$

Comment: In general, the reciprocal may fail to be in $L^2$. You need to place more restrictions on $f$ if you want to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Potato: See edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that, at least under certain conditions, the coefficients of $1/f$ can be obtained from the coefficients of $f$. Per the last comment on [THIS](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=492709) thread, see the following two papers:

["A. Edrei and G. Szegö, “A note on the reciprocal of a Fourier series,” Proc. Am. Math. Soc., vol. 4, no. 2, pp. 323–329, 1953."](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2031811)

["R. Duffin, “The Reciprocal of a Fourier Series,” Proc. Am. Math. Soc., vol. 13, no. 6, pp. 965–970, 1962."](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2034097)

Answer (score 6):

The relationship between the coefficients of $f$ is $1/f$ is  opaque. Consider the special case when    $\hat f\in \ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ (hence, the function $f$ is continuous). If $f$ does not vanish, then the Fourier coefficients of $1/f$ are also in $\ell^1$; this is [Wiener's $1/f$ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_algebra). If you could get the coefficients of $1/f$ directly, you'd have a constructive proof of Wiener's theorem, with some explicit $\ell^1$ norm estimate. But there is not really such a thing, despite some partial results. See the paper [In search of the invisible spectrum](https://eudml.org/doc/75407) by Nikolskii. I remember attending the author's talk titled "Why there exists no constructive proof of Wiener’s $1/f$ theorem?" (as seen [here](http://www.imbm.org.tr/nikolskii-%20may%202008.pdf)) but, sadly, no longer remember the reason why.